# ElasticBeanstalk deployment on custom VPC (None of the instances are sending data)

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-vpc

I have set up a new `VPC` in my AWS account, using their new wizard, which creates all the necessary resources (igw, natgw, public/private subnets, routing tables, etc.)

After spinning up tens of ElasticBeanstalk environments, I have come to conclusion that the instances are not able to reach `elasticbeanstalk-health.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`, and therefore EB fails the initial deployment of the environment:

[image]

##### The EB configuration:

1. Instances are deployed to the public subnets, allocated public IP (**they can reach the internet**)
2. Instances are assigned the default SGs created by EB, **and also the VPC's default SG**.
3. The application load balancer is publicly available, deployed on the public subnets and can reach the instances.

   1. However, the healthcheck fails because nothing responds from the instance's side, because the EB default app is not yet installed.
   2. I can verify the load balancer can reach the instance thanks to opening a socket on the relevant port (`nc -l -p 80`) and seeing the LB healthcheck requests being received.

##### Troubleshooting further:

1. I have SSH'ed into one of the instances and tried connecting EB's health endpoint -- without any success.
2. Testing from my own laptop, the connection succeeds.
3. The issue roots to the DNS resolution of the health endpoint:

   1. From my own computer: `PING elasticbeanstalk-health.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (35.170.164.93)`
   2. From the EB instance: `PING elasticbeanstalk-health.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (10.0.154.188)`
   3. The difference in IPs is not what bothers me, **but what does** is that on the instance the resolved IP begins with `10.0.xxx.xxx` -- **which is configured to be routed to _local_** in the routing tables, as the VPC's default CIDR is `10.0.0.0/16`.
4. Reminder that this is public subnet, so there's no point in associating VPC Endpoint to EB/EB-health endpoints.

I'm wondering why the EB-health hostname is resolved to such IP address, and by whom, as it definitely should be resolved a public IP address available to the internet.

Comment: This happens only in your custom vpc? What about the default vpc?

Comment: in the default vpc everything is perfect. It is related to enabling private DNS resolution for the VPC endpoints configured on the private subnets. I do not understand why yet. (removing the VPC endpoints from the private subnets helped and now the environment is deployed on the public subnets)

Comment: What VPC endpoints? Did you create EB health vpc endpoints in your VPC?

Comment: yes, since I want to be able to deploy EB environments inside a private subnet as well.

Answer (score 0):

VPC [interface endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/create-interface-endpoint.html), unlike VPC [gateway endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/gateway-endpoints.html), have **VPC scope**, not subnet scope. It does not matter if a VPC interface endpoint is created in a single private subnet. All subnets in the VPC are affected by the endpoint.

This explains why you are resolving health checks to 10.0.154.188. So you either have to fix yoru security groups and allow your instance to communicate with the endpoint, or remove the endpoint or disable private address.

Comment: so how can I use the same VPC to deploy EB environments both in the public and the private subnets ? how the ones deployed in the private subnet would be able to communicate with EB services?

Comment: @johni Through NAT gateway or through VPC interface endpoints.

Comment: but you just said that VPC interface endpoints won't do, because they would affect badly the environments deployed on the public subnets. so just natgw?

Comment: @johni It does not work for you because you have mis-configured your setup. Probably security groups? VPC interface endpoint work normally for both private and public subnets.

Comment: it doesn't have to do with sg, because the issue was the resolved IP, which was local to the vpc. this is because I enabled the vpc endpoint's dns private host. Disabling it will probably allow instances in the public subnet to get the real ip of eb's service, but then again, in private subnets the eb's host won't be resolved to a reachable IP, unless going via natgw -- so what is the point in using vpc endpoint in the first place? (unless you only have private subnets)

Comment: @johni I already told you - you have misconfigured VPC and interface endpoints. Your question does not provide any relevant information about your custom VPC setup. Thus its difficult to speculate. You can make new question with those details if you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248194/discussion-between-johni-and-marcin).